# how to set 2 columns of buttons in ReplyKeyboardMarkup - telebot?

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

Well I'm doing a telebot

but the problem is i want my buttons like this:

|   button    | |   button 2   |

|   button 3  | |   button 4   |

but it shows like this:

[image: -]

any solutions please ?

Answer (score 0):

to set a row of buttons:

```
from telebot import types

keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()

keyboard.row("button","button 2")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a width argument for [`InlineKeyboardMarkup`](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup):

```
telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
```

Example code:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("YOUR TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['some_command'])
def some_command_reaction(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    button_foo = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Foo', callback_data='foo')
    button_bar = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Bar', callback_data='bar')
    button_a = types.InlineKeyboardButton('A', callback_data='a')
    button_b = types.InlineKeyboardButton('B', callback_data='b')
    markup.add(button_foo, button_bar, button_a, button_b)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Some text', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handlers(func=lambda call:True)
def answer(callback):
    if callback.message:
        if callback.data == 'bar':
            pass

bot.infinity_polling()
```

How that looks like:
[image: sorry, not enough reputation to send it normally]